# how to get internet on qemu + cloudimg?

Tags: networking, qemu

trying to run a cloudimg in qemu, and i haven't found a way to get internet access, help?  i've set up the cloudimg with

```
wget 'https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img';
mkdir -p ./mnt;
sudo guestmount -a jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img -i --rw ./mnt;
sudo chroot ./mnt /bin/passwd --delete root;
sudo umount mnt;
```

and i'm starting qemu with

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-machine accel=kvm \
-cpu host \
-smp cores=4 \
-m size=1G \
-serial stdio \
-boot menu=on \
-drive media=disk,file=jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img,if=virtio,cache=unsafe,format=qcow2,werror=report
```

and the system starts, and i can login as root, but it doesn't have internet access, ping saying

```
root@ubuntu:~# ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

i have tried granting network access a couple of ways, with

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci
```

and

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nic tap
```

but it doesn't seem to make a difference, still getting `ping: connect: Network is unreachable` , and i'm stuck

Comment: I recommend following https://powersj.io/posts/ubuntu-qemu-cli/ which has examples of networking as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly because the network configuration is missing in the guest OS, and not because of wrong configuration of the VM.

Based on instructions from [1](https://serverascode.com/2018/06/26/using-cloud-images.html) I had success with the following procedure.

Before starting the VM I stripped cloud-init from it, by running

```
virt-customize -a bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --uninstall cloud-init
```

in the host.

Then started the bionic server cloudimg directly with qemu-system-x86_64, passing only this additional option for network

> -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::8888-:22

Inside the VM, logged in as root, I had to configure the network with

```
cd /etc/netplan
nano 01-netcfg.yaml
```

and then adding this content to the created file

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s2:
       dhcp4: true
```

saving and closing it, and then running

```
netplan --debug apply
```

After that, `ifconfig` reported an configured network, and the guest had connection.

Comment: This worked well for me. On bare cloud image (`ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img`) nano and ifconfig are not installed, so 01-netcfg.yaml can be created with `echo "..." > 01-netcfg.yaml` and `ip a` instead if `ifconfig`.